# Make disable input type text on mobile and editable on desktop through CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the input type text to disable through CSS on mobile?

Here is my code:

```
<input id="example" class="ui-timepicker-input" placeholder="" type="text">
```

Since typepad is opening while add select the time on mobile. I want not to open typepad on mobile for slecting time and date picker.

Answer (score 3):

You can mimic the effect using `pointer-events: none;` put these styles into media query for mobile.

```css
#example {
  background: #ccc;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="example" class="ui-timepicker-input" placeholder="" type="text" tabindex="-1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it - if no need or duplicate - one for desktop. one for mobile each set in attributes how you need

Comment: And to do so, use media query.

Answer (score -1):

CSS cannot disable the input, you can however turn off display or visibility.

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
.disable{
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important; //optional
}
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="example" class="ui-timepicker-input disable" placeholder="" type="text">
```

Comment: Not my dv, you don't need to use display and visibility at the same place.

Comment: As i have clearly written turn off either display or visibility.And in the code,i have commented the visibility property as optional .Please read the post properly.Thanks. @bhansa